# SharePoint: How do you reference a localized list?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list that gets installed by a feature.

I need to enable content types which I do so in a feature receiver:

```
SPList list = site.Lists["NameOfList"];
list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
list.Update();
```

The problem is that it seems the method:site.Lists["NameOfList"], is really looking at the Title not the ID.

How can I get the list by using the ID and NOT the title which is subject to change because of Localization...

```
 <ListInstance
    TemplateType="10051" 
    Id="ThisISTheIDField"  //Want to retrieve list instance based on this field.
    Title="$Resources:MyFile,MyResourceName;"
    Url="Lists/URLOFList"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE">
  </ListInstance>
```

Thanks in advance. And 10 years of hail Maries for the MS SharePoint developer who wrote this internal dare I say - c.r.a.p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your list is a custom list, right?

You can add:

```
EnableContentTypes=TRUE
```

To your list definition and you won't need the feature?

See: [List Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091.aspx)

Comment: In theory your suggestion sounds plausable, but this is SharePoint we're talking about, so I will have to really test it to make sure it respects that property.

Comment: LOL.. let go, let go.. embrace The SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

There is no site.Lists (Maybe is a SPWeb? The naming is awkward, I Know)

```
<SPWeb Instance>.Lists.GetList(Guid uniqueId, bool bFetchMetadata)
<SPWeb Instance>.Lists.GetList(Guid uniqueId, bool bFetchMetadata, bool bFetchSecurityData)
<SPWeb Instance>.GetList(string strUrl)
```

The third option could combine the url and use the internal name to grab it (in the URL lists are accessed by the internal name)

Answer (score 0):

If the operation has to be completed only once in a lifetime, I'd suggest looping throuhg the .Lists collection and checking if the baseTemplate matches:

```
For Each oList In web.Lists
    If (list1.BaseTemplate = 10051) Then
         oList.ContentTypesEnabled=True
    End If
Next
```